# ipython not reloading modules

Tags: python, shell, ipython, reload

I'm running IPython in an emacs shell using:

```
;; Set IPython interpreter in my init.el
(defvar python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
(defvar python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

Then:

1. Start IPython with `M-x run-python`
2. Run a program within IPython with `%run myprog.py`. myprog.py imports a module called `mymodule`.

I make changes to `mymodule` but when I run `%run myprog.py` again, it runs the original `mymodule`, not the changed code.

FWIW, I'm using emacs 24.5 prelude, on Windows 10 with Anaconda and Python 3.5.

Comment: Don't see a cache from Emacs side. Assume the wrong file was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that [IPython's `%run` command does not reload modules](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/461).

My current workaround is:

1. Add the code below to `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`
2. Use `$run myprog.py args`

.

```
# this code in `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`
# get_config() is injected into the global namespace whilst
# config files are loaded
c = get_config()

# Autoreload modules
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = ['autoreload']
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%autoreload 2']
```

I didn't realise that `%run` does not reload modules because I'm used to using Spyder's `runfile` command, which does. It's nuts that `%run` doesn't and I'd like to submit a patch to fix it at some point.

On Windows, the HOME environment variable must be set so that the  `run-python` command in `emacs` can read the IPython profile.  If HOME is not set, you can add this to your `init.el`:

```
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                       (progn
                                         (python-shell-send-string-no-output "%load_ext autoreload")
                                         (python-shell-send-string-no-output "%autoreload 2"))))
```