# IPython reloading modified module

Tags: ipython

I'm running `ipython` in Linux terminal. Every time I change my source file I need to restart it; otherwise it uses the old version. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302994/ipython-not-reloading-modules) but it doesn't offer a firm answer. I was wondering if there is anything I could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364050/reloading-submodules-in-ipython) helps. We can use `autoreload` in IPython to make it reload files before executing any new lines.